# Is Payone Supports Tokenization with payment method Paypal,Credit and debit card?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment, payment-gateway

I want to know that is Payone payment method supports tokenization with above methods ? So I can capture amount using token id in future.

Answer (score 0):

Every transaction regarding PAYONE methods can be captured or refunded with one id. This one is called 'txid' in our API.
This unique id will be created with the first payment request to PAYONE as response parameter. But you can handle captures and refunds in between the backend of magento. You can use the normal finish order or refunding flow. If you need more details, please contact the developer.